# cómo pasar un dato repetido a un input desde js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hexadecimal

hice una pequeña app para generar hexadecimales y quiero repetir éstos mismos pero en un showcase de código para poder copiar la sentencia css ya escrita! les dejo el código abajo:

```
<div class="colours">
        <div class="colour">
            <button class="lock-toggle">
                <img src="/lock-open.svg" alt="">
            </button>

            <input type="text" class="colour-input" value="#000000">
            <button class="copy-hex">Copiar!</button>
        </div>

        

        <div class="colour">
            <button class="lock-toggle">
                <img src="/lock-open.svg" alt="">
            </button>

            <input type="text" class="colour-input" value="#000000">
            
            <button class="copy-hex">Copiar!</button>
        </div>

        <div class="colour">
            <button class="lock-toggle">
                <img src="/lock-open.svg" alt="">
            </button>

            <input type="text" class="colour-input" value="#000000">
            <button class="copy-hex">Copiar!</button>
        </div>

        <div class="colour">
            <button class="lock-toggle">
                <img src="/lock-open.svg" alt="">
            </button>

            <input type="text" class="colour-input" value="#000000">
            <button class="copy-hex">Copiar!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ésto con mi app de js ya genera efectivamente el código hexa!

```
    class Colour {
    constructor(hex, element) {
        this.hex = hex;
        this.element = element;
        this.locked = false;
    }

    setHex(hex) {
        this.hex = hex;
        this.element.style.backgroundColor = hex;
        this.element.querySelector(".colour-input").value = hex;
    }

    setLocked(locked) {
        this.locked = locked;

        if (locked) {
            this.element
                .querySelector(".lock-toggle")
                .classList.add("is-locked");

            this.element
                .querySelector("img")
                .src = "./lock-closed.svg";
        } else {
            this.element
                .querySelector(".lock-toggle")
                .classList.remove("is-locked");

            this.element
                .querySelector("img")
                .src = "./lock-open.svg";
        }
    }

    toggleLocked() {
        this.setLocked(!this.locked);
    }

    generateHex() {
        if (this.locked) {
            return
        }
        
        const chars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        let color = "#";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        
        this.setHex(color);
    }

    copyToClipboard() {
        const input = this.element.querySelector(".colour-input");
        input.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        input.blur();

        this.element.classList.add("copied");
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.element.classList.remove("copied");
        }, 1000);
    }
}

const colour_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.colours .colour');

const colours = [];

for (let i = 0; i < colour_elements.length; i++) {
    const colour_element = colour_elements[i];

    const input = colour_element.querySelector(".colour-input");
    const lock_toggle = colour_element.querySelector(".lock-toggle");
    const copy_btn = colour_element.querySelector(".copy-hex");

    const hex = input.value;

    const colour = new Colour(hex, colour_element);

    input.addEventListener('input', (e) => colour.setHex(e.target.value));
    lock_toggle.addEventListener('click', () => colour.toggleLocked());
    copy_btn.addEventListener('click', () => colour.copyToClipboard());

    colour.generateHex();
    colours.push(colour);
}

document.querySelector(".generator-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
        colours[i].generateHex();
    }
});
```

Mi problema radica cuando quiero copiar y pegar el input para escribir en el showcase, que sería el siguiente código:

```
<div class="container colour">
        <p class="language" id="language-copy">CSS</p>
        <div class="code-wrapper">
            <pre>
                <code id="code"></code>
            </pre>
          <button id="copy-button">Copy</button>
        </div>
        <span id="copy-success">Code copied! :)</span>
      </div>
```

cuando copio y pego el input queda en #000000 y no se repite el hexadecimal que genero más arriba. no puedo reutilizar la funcionalidad! quise generarla de nuevo pero ésto lo que hace es generar un hexa aleatorio distinto, entonces me quedaría distinto a los ya generados. Alguno sabe como forzarle el $hex para que quede igual al generado con el botón??

Gracias!! saludos

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es el problema. ¿"_Pegar y copiar el input para escribir en el showcase_"?  ¿Que showcase? La opción de copiar [parece funcionar bien](https://gifyu.com/image/SxBHd).

Comment: cuando quiero reutilizar un input en otra parte del código, no genera el hexa! se queda en #000000 :/